# How can I handle dynamic/customizable fields with playwright and TypeScript?

Tags: dom, html-parsing, playwright-test, playwright-typescript

I am using Playwright in Type Script. How can I handle dynamic fields, which can be text fields, check boxes, or drop down fields? Is there any solution? Because when I hit the URL, the fields on that page are completely dynamic. Sometimes there can be 10 fields (including check boxes, text fields, or drop downs), and other times there could be 20. So, how can I handle this using DOM parsing or any other solution?

Currently, I am only handling the static fields. However, there are some dynamic and custom fields created from the back-end, and I don't know the locator of those fields because they can be different on each test run. If there is any solution please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you on your way: Using the [all() method](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-all) on a locator, returns an array of all the matches. For example, you can get all textboxes or all buttons this way:

```js
const textboxes = await page.getByRole('textbox').all()
const buttons = await page.getByRole('button').all()
```

Then you can iterate over the array and do stuff with all fields:

```js
// Fills all textboxes
for (const textbox of textboxes) {
    await textbox.fill('Stuff')
}

// Clicks on all buttons
for (const button of buttons) {
    await button.click()
}
```